# tomcat6 with crl doesn't load

Tags: tomcat, openssl, client-certificate

I have a new tomcat6.0.34 setup I'm configuring on my CentOS 6.3 (64 bit). I've downloaded a series of CRLs for the certificate authorities I am using, converted them from DER to PEM with openssl:

`openssl crl -inform DER -outform PEM -in f1.der -out f1.pem_crl`

`openssl crl -inform DER -outform PEM -in f2.der -out f2.pem_crl`

I then build a crl bundle with all the pem_crls (ends up with a 283 MB crl):

`cat *.pem_crl > CRL-bundle.crl`

Finally, I move it to /etc/ssl/certs

`mv CRL-bundle.crl /etc/ssl/certs`

I configure my connector as follows:

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
       SSLEnabled="true"
       maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
       maxThreads="150"
       minSpareThreads="25"
       maxSpareThreads="75"
       enableLookups="false"
       acceptCount="100"
       disableUploadTimeout="true"
       compression="on"
       compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/
       javascript,application/xml,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"
       connectionTimeout="20000"
       secure="true"
       keystorePass="mykeystorepass"
       truststoreFile="/etc/ssl/certs/my.truststore"
       truststorePass="mytruststorepass"
       clientAuth="true"
       sslProtocol="TLS"
       crlFile="/etc/ssl/certs/CRL-bundle.crl"
       redirectPort="8443" />
```

When I try to start tomcat6 like that, only one entry appears in my catalina.out

```
    Nov 20, 2012 8:58:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
```

If I remove the crlFile reference in the server.xml, everything works fine (except crl lookups of course). The system starts up, the app is accessible, it prompts for the certificate...

Any thoughts on why it would be failing like that would be appreciated.